# My IIS processes keep get frozen so web site hangs up during that time

Tags: iis, freeze

I can't debug the problem but apparently some coding problems cause it to break down and get reset IIS processes. I want to modify it as a way it will work with multiple processes so 1 process fail won't cause web site to hang up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click application pool and then click advanced settings at the right

Change Maximum Worker Processes to the number you want to multiply.

But at this scenario you also have to change your session state. You can use sql server or stateserver which i suggest.

You have to configure your web config like this

```
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to segregate the applications into separate application pools (this can be done through IIS Manager). An IIS application pool is managed by a worker process, so many applications running in the same pool run the risk of collapsing if one of the applications causes unexpected behaviour.

That aside, you really need to understand why the application itself is causing problems. Have you tried running the application through Visual Studio and Casini (or IIS Express)?